# MySQL - How to update atable based on an internal ordering of the table

Tags: mysql

If I make a selection from my MySQL table like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY country_id, category
```

I get the following table:

```
+------------+----------+-------+
| country_id | category | order |
+------------+----------+-------+
|          1 |        A |     0 |
|          1 |        B |     0 |
|          1 |        F |     0 |
|          3 |        A |     0 |
|          3 |        C |     0 |
|          5 |        B |     0 |
|          5 |        L |     0 |
|          5 |        P |     0 |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

What I would like to do is update the `order` column so that the value of that column is the order of that row for it's country_id. In other words the  final table should look like this:

```
+------------+----------+-------+
| country_id | category | order |
+------------+----------+-------+
|          1 |        A |     1 |
|          1 |        B |     2 |
|          1 |        F |     3 |
|          3 |        A |     1 |
|          3 |        C |     2 |
|          5 |        B |     1 |
|          5 |        L |     2 |
|          5 |        P |     3 |
+------------+----------+-------+
```

If I use the original query given at the top in a subquery, that would give me the correct order but I can't figure out how to iterate through the table and suspect I thinking about it wrongly.

How can I get this result?

Many thanks

Comment: A note: there is no internal order, in theory you can get different order every time you run the query.

Comment: I don't understand @Karolis. It is ordering on the number of the `country_id` and then the letters in `category` isn't it? That will give the same order each time.

Comment: Are there identical pairs (country_id, category)?

Comment: @Joe Oich...pardon. I haven't read your query carefully. The term **internal** confused me.

Comment: @Devart - No, there won't be any duplicates.

Comment: @Karolis there's an internal order, when a primary key exists and table is InnoDB (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this query -

```
UPDATE mytable t1
  JOIN (
    SELECT t1.country_id, t1.category, COUNT(*) `order`
    FROM mytable t1
    LEFT JOIN mytable t2
      ON t2.country_id = t1.country_id AND t2.category <= t1.category
    GROUP BY
      t1.country_id, t1.category
  ) t2
  ON t1.country_id = t2.country_id AND t1.category = t2.category
SET t1.`order` = t2.`order`
```

As an aside note, you can remove `order` field from the table because this can calculated this on the fly.